# How do I move my applications from /Applications to ~/Applications on MacOS

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

simple question,

**How do I move my applications from /Applications to ~/Applications**?

This is on macOS Catalina

Comment: https://osxdaily.com/2011/12/29/move-apps-out-of-the-applications-folder-in-os-x-lion/

Comment: You simply hold the Command key while dragging it to ```~/Applications``` from ```/Applications```.

Comment: It doesn’t let me. If I drag it creates a shortcut alias instead even when I press shift

Comment: Are you trying to move the preinstalled Apple applications, or applications from the App store, or manually-installed applications, or what?

Comment: The osx daily link is a good read--thanks for posting @moab. Out of interest, can you tell us why you would want to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use drag and drop or terminal

Drag and drop: Open 2 finder windows one with ~/Applications and one with /Applications then drag the app.

Terminal: open terminal spotlight search terminal enter.
Type cp file to move where you what the file

Done

Comment: The question is, why would you want to do that? The /Application directory is system-wide, as it's supposed to be, because it contains the applications *you* installed on your Mac, but also the applications that came pre-installed (Safari, iTunes, etc...), plus Utilities, that are supposed to be in that directory, not in any user's. The ~/Application under your username isn't meant to host applications per se, just aliases, and some user-specific app-related files, that's it.

Comment: I don’t know why.

Comment: That’s right why.

Comment: It's easy enough to try and check what you can do and not do in macOS when it comes to applications: you download the .dmg file for an application you'd like to install, and drag-drop its content in the ~/Applications folder instead of /Applications, and you see what happens. Some apps ask you if you want to install for the current user only or all users on your Mac; those usually require you to enter your admin password if you want to install them system-wide. Moving apps from the /Applications folder to ~/Applications doesn't make sense to me, but maybe it does to the OP, for some reason.

Comment: I guess that could be the case